# HP G56-129WM wireless Completely Broken, Driver Based

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, drivers

Friend wants me to fix up his HP G56. I made a fresh install of Windows 7 and installed the graphics card driver. Next I wanted to install the driver for the wireless networkcard.

I tried all the drivers from here: http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=4332803&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=4247525&swLang=13&taskId=135&swEnvOID=4063

None of those do anything - the one at the top did get me into the actual installation until it said that the wireless adapter was unplugged.

Restarting, pressing F12 has no effect. It will, however, pick up the ethernet driver and say in troubleshooting that an ethernet cable is unplugged. Worst part is wireless was just fine before the wipe & reinstall of W7 so I know it's driver based.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the battery compartment for the exact number of your laptop, there many types of G 56's
and proceed using the exact model number.

Second, delete the bad driver,  then install the recommended driver from HP,using the number taken as we said above,  if this driver fail, install the generic one recommended by Microsoft via Windows update.

Third , check your internet connection. This will be enough.